# Сортировка четных элементов массива в Java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, числа

Всем привет!
В данный момент я решаю такую задачу:нужно реализовать публичный статический метод **getSameParity()**, который принимает на вход массив чисел и возвращает новый, состоящий из элементов, у которых такая же чётность, как и у первого элемента входного массива. Если на вход был передан пустой массив, метод возвращает также пустой массив.

**Пример работы программы:**

```
int[] numbers1 = {};
App.getSameParity(numbers1); // []
 
int[] numbers2 = {1, 2, 3};
App.getSameParity(numbers2); // [1, 3]
 
int[] numbers3 = {1, 2, 8};
App.getSameParity(numbers3); // [1]
 
int[] numbers4 = {2, 2, 8};
App.getSameParity(numbers4); // [2, 2, 8]
 
int[] numbers5 = {-3, 2, 1};
App.getSameParity(numbers5); // [-3, 1]
```

**Уточнение к задаче:**

Проверку чётности следует выполнять, используя остаток от деления на 2: **item % 2 == 0**
В массиве могут находится **отрицательные числа**. Для работы с ними использовать метод нахождения модуля **Math.abs()**

```
  Math.abs(-1); // 1

  Math.abs(1); // 1

  Math.abs(0); // 0
```

Так как мы не знаем заранее, какое количество элементов будет в новом массиве, можно изначально создать массив с "запасом", а затем отрезать лишнее. Для этого может понадобиться метод **Arrays.copyOfRange()**, который принимает на вход массив чисел и возвращает часть его элементов в виде нового массива:

```
int[] numbers = {3, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1};

// получаем элементы с 1-го индекса включительно по 4-й не включительно 

var range = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 0, 4);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(range));

// => [3, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Мое решение:**

```
package com.arrays.problem6;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  
        }

    public static Integer getSameParity(int[] numbers){

            int i = 0, j = numbers.length - 1;

            if(Math.abs(numbers[i]%2)!= Math.abs(numbers[j])% 2) {
                i++;
                if(Math.abs(numbers[i])% 2 == Math.abs(numbers[j])% 2) {
                    return numbers[i-1];
                }
                j--;
                if(Math.abs(numbers[i])%2 == Math.abs(numbers[j])%2) {
                    return numbers[j+1];
                }
            }

            while(i < j) {
                if(Math.abs(numbers[i])%2 != Math.abs(numbers[j])%2) {
                    if(Math.abs(numbers[i])%2 == Math.abs(numbers[0])%2) {
                        return numbers[j];
                    }else {
                        return numbers[i];
                    }
                }
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        int[] range=Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers,0,4);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(range));
            return numbers[i];

        }
    }
```

Программа не работает, хотя подозреваю,что я близок к правильному решению.Помогите мне пожалуйста решить эту задачу.

Comment: Что должен возвращать `getSameParity` ?

Comment: getSameParity() должен вернуть новый массив чисел, состоящий из элементов,у которых такая же четность как и у первого элемента входного массива.

Comment: непонятно , что такое "такая же четность". четные элементы в массиве мы нашли, что с ними делать дальше?

Comment: В вашем коде `getSameParity` возвращает целое число вместо массива. Вы уверены что вы близки к правильному решению?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy  - эту ошибку я уже исправил, метод gegtSameParity все равно не проводит сортировку так,как нужно.

Comment: Исправьте код в вопросе, проявите внимание к тем кто занимается вашим вопросом. :)

Comment: @Дмитрий, вывести на экран и вернуть в метод.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, сделано.

Comment: Спасибо. Только этот код даже не компилируется. Приведите, пожалуйста, его в компилируемое состояние.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я заменил тип возвращаемого значения на ссылочный Integer,но результата это особо не дало.

Comment: Вы по-прежнему считаете что были близки? :)

Comment: Нет, это было ошибочное суждение,сформулированное в час ночи)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделять с запасом, затем обрезать - не наш метод. Наш метод - сосчитать длину ответа, выделить сколько надо, заполнить.

Проверка чётности отрицательных чисел ничем не отличается от проверки чётности положительных. Для некоторых других остатков (больших двух) некоторая разница есть, но тут не надо беспокоиться.

```
public static int[] getSameParity(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return new int[0];
    }

    boolean parity = isEven(numbers[0]);

    int n = 0;
    for (int v : numbers) {
        if (isEven(v) == parity) {
            ++n;
        }
    }

    int[] answer = new int[n];
        
    int j = 0;
    for (int v : numbers) {
        if (isEven(v) == parity) {
            answer[j++] = v;
        }
    }
    assert(j == n);

    return answer;
}

private static boolean isEven(int n) {
    return n % 2 == 0;
}
```

Код грешит дублированием - два одинаковых цикла с одинаковыми условиями. Это породная особенность `C`-подобных языков в отсутствии нормальных контейнеров. От дублирования можно избавиться, да решение станет значительно сложнее. А мы тут учимся, оставим как есть.

### Дополнение

Избавимся от дублирования совсем:

```
public static int[] getSameParity(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return new int[0];
    }
    boolean parity = isEven(numbers[0]);
    return Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(v -> isEven(v) == parity).toArray();
}
```

Comment: то есть ,Вы решили проблему дублирования при помощи ключевого слова assert  и введения дополнительного булевского метода isEven?

Comment: благодарю Вас!Очень элегантное решение.

Comment: Не совсем. `assert` показывает где будут проблемы если программист поправит один цикл и забудет про другой. Но да, `isEven` призван упростить насколько возможно проблемное место (которое - два цикла).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarsky, насколько я понял,смысл assert таков:


    1)указываем ключевое слово assert,
    2)пишем выражение или вызываем метод, результатом которого будет булево выражение (true или false),
    3) после двоеточия можем указать некоторое строковое сообщение, которое будет передано вместе с ошибкой. В общем случае может быть не просто строка, а любое выражение, которое возвращает что-то отличное от void.

Comment: Вы поняли правильно. В `Java` ассерты почти бесполезны - они отключены по умолчанию и не рекомендованы к использованию. Это просто документация для другого прогрммиста "хочу чтобы оба счётчика были равны".

Comment: В общем, ассерт нужен для автоматизированного тестирования.

Comment: тогда уже так: Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(v -> isEven(v) == isEven(numbers[0])).toArray();

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать

```
private static int[] getSameParity(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) return new int[]{};
    return Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(getIntPredicate(numbers[0])).toArray();
}

private static IntPredicate getIntPredicate(int firstElement) {
    return number ->  Math.abs(number % 2) == Math.abs(firstElement % 2);
}
```

либо так, что в общем одно и тоже почти

```
private static int[] getSameParity(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0) return new int[]{};
    int remainder = getRemainder(numbers[0]);
    return Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(value -> getRemainder(value) == remainder).toArray();
}

private static int getRemainder(int n) {
    return  Math.abs(n % 2);
}
```

Comment: стримы мне пока тяжело даются ,но в общем да.

Comment: @PeteAlexandrovich зато с ними выглядит намного понятнее раздутого кода, но конечно не всегда)

Comment: ,согласен с вами.